# Drupal VS Zikula

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, zikula

Im new to drupal (just finished my first web site with it), i found it very simple and powerfull to use.

Recently, i've been asked to build a community with Zikula.

They prefer to use zikula becose it is the 'evolution' of phpnuke, that is the cms that they currently use (i have 'restayling and rebuild' it).

Moreover, I want learn and use just 1 cms.

So, what are the main differences between drupal and zikula?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of one and other?

Why should I choose Drupal or Zikula?

p.s: i know that the most of the times the answer is 'its all about your needs', but this is supposed to be a general question

Comment: Added subjective tag as this is quite a subjective question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [google trends](http://google.com/trends?q=drupal%2C+Zikula%2C+phpnuke&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0) Blue is drupal, yellow is phpnuke and red is zikula.

[drupal phpnuke zikula http://google.com/trends/viz?q=drupal,+Zikula,+phpnuke&date=all&geo=all&graph=weekly_img&sort=0&sa=N](http://google.com/trends/viz?q=drupal,+Zikula,+phpnuke&date=all&geo=all&graph=weekly_img&sort=0&sa=N)

You would want to learn something with a future. They would want something they could find support in. I would say it is not yet Zikulas hour.

Comment: The most people use a cms, the most help you'll find, thats true, but following the chart, i would be fine using joomla: http://google.com/trends?q=drupal%2C+Zikula%2C+phpnuke%2C+joomla&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

The usage stat is a parameter, i would like to have others

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of Zikulas ; I've been working with Drupal for a couple of months -- and heard about Drupal a lot this last year and a half.

If I had to choose one CMS, I would go with the solution that has :

- the most support
- is the most used
- has good reputation -- or, at least, a not too bad one

Between Zikulas and Drupal, the choice is obvious : Drupal is the one I would learn, not Zikulas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Zikula and in the past with postnuke (not phpnuke!). I like the multilanguage system and the secutity.

Answer (score 0):

Zikula is ok but I would say hands down Drupal.

Here are reviews of both of them here: [CMS Critic reviews](http://www.cmscritic.com/categories/2-CMS-Reviews)

Answer (score 0):

There's still some caveats in Drupal and YES you'll have to do things by hand if you want a completely cohesive system, but at the end of the day (and of the learning curve) you'll get something pretty solid in not too long time.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Zikula for years, way back when it was PostNuke to now. The system has moved to using Symfony, Doctrine, twig, bootstrap, and all sorts of other cutting edge tech. Yes, the community is small, but I really feel like it is going to break out now. Over the years I have evaluated other technologies including Drupal and Joomla, but they just never had the right fit for what I was trying to do. (That is somewhat because of my familiarity with Zikula I am sure.)

I cannot really give you a comparison because I have not used both extensively and anything I would say would be unfair to Drupal. I will say there are WAY more modules for Drupal.

Since your client wants to use zikula, I would also suggest you do what they ask. If I was employing you, and you were fighting me on the cms I am using, I would probably start looking for someone else.

Anything you do learn will be useful in many other instances.

Good luck in your efforts

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why no one is mentioning the amount of server resources required to run Drupal. It is great, but if you are planning to run a community site that will grow large someday, then I would rather you not try Drupal.

I am now using Zikula and it is not bad.